# Android ndk build error: expected a platform name, e.g., 'macos'

Tags: android-ndk

I'm building a project from github using android ndk and I got many errors like this. What are possible solutions to fix this?

```
C:/Users/juju/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/build/../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/bits/fortify/string.h:35:54: error:
      expected a platform name, e.g., 'macos'
void* __memchr_chk(const void*, int, size_t, size_t) __INTRODUCED_IN(23);
                                                     ^
C:/Users/juju/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/build/../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/android/versioning.h:62:36: note:
      expanded from macro '__INTRODUCED_IN'
#define __INTRODUCED_IN(api_level) __BIONIC_AVAILABILITY(introduced=api_level)
                                   ^
C:/Users/juju/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/build/../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/android/versioning.h:57:71: note:
      expanded from macro '__BIONIC_AVAILABILITY'
#define __BIONIC_AVAILABILITY(__what) __attribute__((__availability__(android,strict,__what)))
                                                                      ^
<command line>:4:17: note: expanded from macro 'android'
#define android 1
                ^
```